# aws lambda layer: S3 bucket: not getting updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda layer created from s3 bucket source

[image]

I keep updating the zip file.

But the lambda code does not seem to use the updated zip file from the layer

Currenlty i have to create new version of layer, pointing to the same s3 file path.

Comment: This is correct.  When you create a layer, you are directly, or indirectly via S3, uploading the contents to the layer.  Regardless of where the data comes from, you will need to create a new version of the layer when you want to update it.